# Select sum of a column without cursor

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data as:

```
ID   LENGTH_IN_CM
1        1.0
2        1.0
3        9.0
4        5.0
5        15.0
6        3.0
7        5.0
```

I know that a page is 20cm long and would like to calculate which pages each item will be on.

So for example items with id 1, 2, 3, and 4 will be on the first page (1.0 + 1.0 + 9.0 + 5.0 < 20.0) but 5 and 6 will be on the second and 7 on the third.

Is it possible to calculate the page numbers without using a cursor?

Comment: Do you want to do this without a cursor because you're using a cursor now and it's slow, or do you want to do this without a cursor because you've heard or read that cursors are bad? In some cases (like running totals, and possibly this one), cursors are the most efficient *supported* option.

Comment: This isn't the only thing I need, I'll use a cursor anyway at one point, but for this purpose, I should do it without a cursor so at the end I won't end up with 3 cursors.. There will be like 7k rows and have lots of rules (paging resets when 3 columns (x,y,z) changes. So if I use a cursor for this, I'm most certain that I'll need to use 3 or 4 to do what I need.

Comment: Or perhaps the same cursor could be used to loop through all the rows exactly once and make multiple decisions at each step.

Comment: Mikael, that doesn't quite work. Change the value of ID 7 from 6 to 5 and it places the 15, 3, and 5 on page 2 which shouldn't happen.

Comment: Derek, your answer was the correct one. 40/20 = 2 and that should be the last line of second page, not third. Why did you delete it?

Comment: @DerekKromm You are correct. I blame the test data :).

Comment: The last row can't be on the second page, since 15 + 3 + 6 > 20. You said so yourself in the question.

Comment: As Aaron said originally, this is the type of problem that likely benefits from using a cursor. If you try to complicate this using some sort of recursive CTE (or who knows what else), you'll probably run into worse performance than simply going row-by-row and evaluating as needed.

Comment: tell me the reason why you downvoted me so I would know what I was doing wrong. cos I won't give up

Comment: @tcoder why do you think posting three incorrect answers, all of which exhibit the same problem you've been told about multiple times, is any better than just posting one incorrect answer? If you can improve your query so that it actually gives the right results, update one answer, don't just add another. There is a reason you get a prompt that says "Are you sure you want to add another answer?" In this case all it is doing for you is getting you more down-votes than you would get if you only had one incorrect answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I did this more for the challenge than because I necessarily think it's a good idea. I'm inclined to believe Aaron that a cursor may be more appropriate. Anyhow:

```
declare @Items table (ID int not null,LENGTH_IN_CM decimal(5,1) not null)
insert into @Items(ID,LENGTH_IN_CM) values
(1,1.0),
(2,1.0),
(3,9.0),
(4,5.0),
(5,15.0),
(6,3.0),
(7,6.0)

;With PossiblePages as (
    select ID as MinID,ID as MaxID,LENGTH_IN_CM as TotalLength from @Items
    union all
    select MinID,MaxID + 1,CONVERT(decimal(5,1),TotalLength + LENGTH_IN_CM)
    from
        PossiblePages pp
            inner join
        @Items it
            on
                pp.MaxID + 1 = it.ID
    where
        TotalLength + LENGTH_IN_CM <= 20.0
), LongPages as (
    select MinID,MAX(MaxID) as MaxID,MAX(TotalLength) as TotalLength from PossiblePages group by MinID
), FinalPages as (
    select MinID,MaxID,TotalLength from LongPages where MinID = 1
    union all
    select lp.MinID,lp.MaxID,lp.TotalLength
    from
        LongPages lp
            inner join
        FinalPages fp
            on
                lp.MinID = fp.MaxID + 1
), PageNumbers as (
    select MinID,MaxID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MinID) as PageNo
    from FinalPages
)
select * from PageNumbers
```

Result:

```
MinID       MaxID       PageNo
----------- ----------- --------------------
1           4           1
5           6           2
7           7           3
```

Which should be easy enough to join back to the original table, if you want to assign a page number to each row.

`PossiblePages` calculates every possible page - for every row, it acts as if that row is the first one on that page, and then works out how many additional rows can be appended to that, and the total length that that range of rows represents (there may be cleaner ways to calculate this expression, not sure at the moment).

`LongPages` then finds the longest value that `PossiblePages` calculated, for each starting row number.

Finally, `FinalPages` starts with the first page (that must, logically, be the one started with `ID` 1 - you can always introduce another calculation if you're not guaranteed to start at 1, and need to find the earliest). Then, the next page is the one that starts from the row ID one higher than the previous row.

You don't *need* `PageNumbers`, but as I said, I was thinking of joining back to the original table.

---

And as predicted by the commenters, I don't think this is going to perform well - just on the sample, I'm seeing at least 4 table scans to compute this.

---

Bonus insanity. This one only scans the table 3 times:

```
;With PageRows as (
    select ID as MinID,ID as MaxID,LENGTH_IN_CM as TotalLength from @Items where ID=1
    union all
    select MinID,MaxID + 1,CONVERT(decimal(5,1),TotalLength + LENGTH_IN_CM)
    from
        PageRows pr
            inner join
        @Items ir
            on
                pr.MaxID = ir.ID-1
    where
        TotalLength + LENGTH_IN_CM <= 20.0
    union all
    select ir.ID as MinID,ir.ID as MaxID,ir.LENGTH_IN_CM as TotalLength
    from
        PageRows pr
            inner join
        @Items ir
            on
                pr.MaxID = ir.ID-1
    where
        TotalLength + LENGTH_IN_CM > 20.0
), PageNumbers as (
    select MinID,MAX(MaxID) as MaxID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MinID) as PageNo
    from PageRows
    group by MinID
)
select * from PageNumbers
```

Comment: +1 for bravery. Though you might be able to use <= 20, in case a set of rows fits perfectly on a page?

Answer (score 0):

This also worked. Tell me why these approaches don't satisfy your need

```
declare @mytable as table(id int, LENGTH_IN_CM int)

insert into @mytable values
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,9),
(4,5),
(5,15),
(6,3),
(7,6);


Select t.id ,
(select floor(SUM(LENGTH_IN_CM)/20.0)+1 page from @myTable  where id<=t.id) 
from @mytable t 


id          Page
----------- ---------------------------------------
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           2
6           2
7           3

(7 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Let's take Aaron's often added comment that switching ID 7's length from 6 to 5 will report it as being on page 2, which it should not be. The problem with this approach is it treats the size of any particular page as 20+any unused space in previous pages, rather than just 20